# how to ensure loading animation will play while another heavy UI is rendering?

Tags: android, performance, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using Jetpack Compose to make an app and I've got 2 composables: VeryLongProductsGrid and LoadingSpinner.

Since the products grid is very long and our target device's got a very limited hardware: rendering this grid always takes quite some time (about 5 seconds).

Because of that, we need a loading spinner. This spinner **is not for representing data fetching**, but so the user won't think the app has stopped working and wait.

This is what I've got and what is happening.

- this gif won't play while the grid is rendering (shouldn't be the case);
- it doesn't matter if the spinner is a GIF or an animation;
- the grid is **NOT loaded using lazy grid** (due to hardware limitation);
- the grid is made using a list of chunked lists (3), column and rows.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ProductListScreen() {

    VeryLongProductsGrid() { 
      // a very long grid here...
      chunkedProducts.forEachIndexed { index, products ->
            Row(

            ) {
                products.forEach { product ->

                    Surface(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(horizontal = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.card_side_margin))
                            .padding(bottom = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.card_bottom_margin))
                            .shadow(
                                dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.card_elevation),
                                MaterialTheme.shapes.card
                            )
                    ) {
                        PhotoListItem(
                            product,
                            viewModel = viewModel,
                            orderLines = orderLines,
                            onClick = {
                                playClickSound(context)
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Box(
        modifier
            .background(Color.White)
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        // loading spinner
        GifImage()
    }

}

@Composable
fun GifImage(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(context)
        .components {
            if (SDK_INT >= 28) {
                add(ImageDecoderDecoder.Factory())
            } else {
                add(GifDecoder.Factory())
            }
        }
        .build()
    Image(
        painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
            ImageRequest.Builder(context).data(data = R.drawable.progress).apply(block = {
                size(coil.size.Size.ORIGINAL)
            }).build(), imageLoader = imageLoader
        ),
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    )
}
```

I know lazy grid would actually help loading the grid faster, but it lags when the user scrolls too fast due to our target device having a very slow CPU. This is not an issue when I'm not using lazy grid, but will take longer to show a responsive UI.

Comment: Why would you use an image for the spinner you can use the built in jetpack compose CircularProgressIndicator

Comment: @AymanAit you mean from material? I've tried it, but it won't play until the UI's rendered.